# Loop an array with nested select LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, subquery

I have the following data structure (just a exemplary visual representation):

```
list<customer>
{
    customer
    {
        name
        orders[]
        {
            order
            {
                quantity
                product
                {
                    price
                }
            }
            order
            {
                ...
            }
            order
            {
                ...
            }
    }
    customer
    {
        ...
    }
    customer
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And I want to acquire the name of each Customer and the total sum of his orders (qty*product price). Now I have the following:

```
var sumEachCust = from c in customers
                  let sum = 0.0m
                  select new
                  {
                     c.Name,
                     sum =+ (from o in c.Orders
                             select o.Product.Price * o.Quantity).FirstOrDefault()
                  };
```

If the `Customer` object has more than one `Order` entry in its `Orders[]`, then I want the sum of all the entries inside. But with this query I get the sum just for the first order.

If I make it this way:

```
var sumEachCust = from c in customers
                  let sum = 0.0m
                  from o in c.Orders
                  select new
                  {
                    c.Name,
                    sum =+ o.Product.Price * o.Quantity
                  };
```

then I will get the name as many times as there are order entities in the `Orders[]` property of the `Customer` object, and I don't want that.

Simply - just once name and sum of all orders.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from c in customers
select new
{
     Name = c.name,
     OrderTotal = c.orders.Sum(o => o.product.price * o.quantity)
}
```

---

If you *really* want to use `let` then here is how you would do that for this scenario

```
from c in customers
let sum = c.orders.Sum(o => o.product.price * o.quantity)
select new
{
    Name = c.name,
    OrderTotal = sum
}
```

Comment: Works and is a really clean and simple solution! Thanks a lot! Nevertheless, could you give me an example using `let` and temporary variable in the query, since I was going that way and would like to see how to correctly use a nested `select` statement in this case?

Comment: @Milkncookiez see update, although you really don't need to use `let` at all here.

Comment: sorry, I wanted to ask about an example with a `nested select`, because for example, if I have to sum the orders of all customers together into one total sum (instead of summing the orders of each customer separately), then how would I do that? (given that I am not completely sure how to use the iteration logic of nested query).

Comment: @Milkncookiez to return the sum of *all* the records then you can simply do `let sum = customers.Sum(x => x.orders.Sum(o => o.product.price * o.quantity))` - bare in mind this will result in a separate query though.